# How can I add into a Razor View a panel created from code behind ext.NET (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, extjs, razor, ext.net

I want to create an ext.NET Panel in a back-end class somewhere in my project.  Then, inside a razor view, I want to instantiate this class and use it to place the component to the screen.  I need help with this latter part!

For example, I have the class:

```
namespace Interface.Resources
{

    public class Screen
    {

        public ext.Panel NavigationPanel()
        {
            ext.Panel navPanel = new ext.Panel
            {
                Title = "NAVIGATION",
                Border = true,
                Header = false,
                Region = ext.Region.East,
                Width = 400,
                Collapsible = true,
                CollapseMode = ext.CollapseMode.Mini,
                Split = true
            };

            return navPanel;

        }
....
```

Now, the view class looks something like this...

```
@using Interface.Resources

@functions
{
    Interface.Resources.Screen _irs = new Interface.Resources.Screen();
}

@_irs.NavigationPanel()

....
```

Clearly the latter is not working... it compiles and runs, but I get an error.  What am I doing wrong... I have tried using Html.X() etc., but I can't seem to get the panel to render.

Note: If I use something like Html.X().Panel()....Items(items => { items.add(_irs.NavigationPanel()); }) ... it works, but I don't want to have to create the container Panel in the razor view every time I use the Interface Resource library that I am creating.

I appreciate that this issue is not Razor specific.

Comment: well can you create an asp.net mvc control and pass it in the same way to the view? i think the only way is to create a config object in your class instead of the panel it self and in the view instead of `@_irs.NavigationPanel()` use `@(Html.X().Panel(_irs.NavigationPanelConfig))`

Comment: I posted a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think your only way is to build the config in your classes then call the ext extension methods to render the panel in the view.

**The Definition**

```
namespace Interface.Resources
{
    public class Screen
    {
        public static Ext.Net.Panel NavigationPanelConfig()
        {
            return new Ext.Net.Panel.Config()
            {
                Title = "NAVIGATION",
                Border = true,
                Header = false,
                Region = Ext.Net.Region.East,
                Width = 400,
                Collapsible = true,
                CollapseMode = Ext.Net.CollapseMode.Mini,
                Split = true,
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**The Render**

```
@(Html.X().Panel(Interface.Resources.Screen.NavigationPanelConfig()))
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  I did manage to get this working... I'll post the example.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that I found was to use the view-port to place the panel into.  It must have been something to do with the view chain that I was implementing in.

```
@(
 Html.X().Viewport()
    .Layout(LayoutType.Border)
    .Items(items =>
        {
            items.Add(_menu.NavigationPanel(Model));
            items.Add(_tabPanel.MainScreen());
        })
)
```

Comment: MEYWD, I asked another question under a different user account (don't know how I managed that)... could you please take a look at it... it's about using the accordion layout.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556453/ext-net-accordion-is-not-working-correctly-mvc

Comment: MEYWD, what's the difference with using the "Config" object rather than the main object?  What are the config objects generally used for, and what's their limitations?

Comment: I will check your question later today, as for the config, every Ext.NET component can be initialized by a config which simply is an object that has initial properties, now the config object has the same properties as the component you want to initialize, but its not actually a component just a property bag, and since you can't render ext components in the view without calling `HTML.X().[ComponentName]` there is no value in creating the component in code behind, create the config for that component then pass it to the render extension method `HTML.X().[ComponentName](Config)`

Comment: now your solution here is fine, however if you want to add a component without a viewport, then you will need to use config objects

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I shall try the config route that you describe.  I understand better now.